# How put some variable in Nav widget

Tags: php, yii2

I did links from `Html::a` and get them parameter `type`, and now I want to put this links to header and I'm trying to change main layout. I put link like that:

```
['label' => 'USA', 'url' => ['index.php/rates'], 'type' => ['USA']],
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this in layout?

I put parameter in action in my Controller like that:

```
public function actionIndex($type = 'USA')
{
}
```

Comment: answer given by **scaisEdge** should work for you. What is your expected output, explain in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this way

```
    ['label' => 'USA', 
          'url' => ['index.php/rates?type=USA]],
```

or for vars

```
   ['label' => 'USA', 
          'url' => ['index.php/rates?type='. $my_var]],
```

If you need to pass parameter form a controller/action to a view or a layout

you can use

```
  use Yii;

  Yii::$app->view->params['your_param'] = 'your_value';
```

then in controller/action you can assign  a value to a param this way :

```
  public function actionYourAction()
  {
    .........
    $this->view->params['your_param'] = 'your_value';
```

Then in  your layout you can

```
  echo $this->params['your_param'];
```

Comment: I know how to do the first but I need to put parameter "type"